# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, ado.net

I tried to save a record from a query into a `DataRow`, but did not make it. I could need some help. This my code:

```
private DataSet CreateDataSet()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    // create Countries table and columns
    DataTable dtApplications = ds.Tables.Add("Applications");
    DataColumn dtApplicationID = dtApplications.Columns.Add("ApplicationID", typeof(int));
    DataColumn dtApplicationName= dtApplications.Columns.Add("ApplicationName", typeof(string));

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MoahannedConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select AppID,AppName from Application", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlDataReader sdr = null;
    dt.TableName = "Application";
    con.Open();
    sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
       AddDataToTable(dtApplicationID, dtApplicationName, dtApplications, ds);
    }
}

private void AddDataToTable(DataColumn ID, DataColumn Name, DataTable myTable,DataSet ds)
{
    DataRow row;
    row = myTable.NewRow();
    row["ApplicationID"] = ID;
    row["ApplicationName"] = Name;
    myTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DataAdapter` directly to [load a `DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx):

```
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select AppID,AppName from Application", con))
{
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

The rest of the code above is redundant in my opinion.

Side-note: You're getting the exception because you want to pass a field of a record to a DataRow's field. But actually you're passing the `DataColumn`.

This would work but is unnecessary:

```
row["ApplicationID"] = sdr.GetInt32(sdr.GetOrdinal("ApplicationID"));
row["ApplicationName"] = sdr.GetString(sdr.GetOrdinal("ApplicationName"));
```

Where `sdr` is your `DataReader`.

Comment: When you try which code? You should just use the first approach using `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`.

Comment: Then i don't understand your compiler which _shows_ "(ApplicationID)". My `da.Fill(dt);` doesn't contain `ApplicationID`.